# Is it possible to install global node packages offline?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, global, offline

I need to be able to install the carto module on an offline server. Is there a way that I could package up  carto with all of its dependencies, and install it on a server that has no connection to the internet.
The server won't have an initial connection, and will have npm and node installed from a .deb archive.

I've tried using npm-offline, as well as npm-offline-packer. These both require that I have an npm registry or a node project.

I'm hoping to have a start script that can run the required commands and get all packages installed. So far, I'm able to install all ubuntu software, just stuck on node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative would be installing it in another machine and copying the package(s) you want inside npm's global `node_modules`.

```
npm config get prefix
```

Gets the path to where it is installed. `node_modules` are usually under `lib/` folder. Module executables could be located under `bin/`. Having both should be enough to use your global module in another machine.

Since you're looking for a start script the steps you need are:

1. Getting npm prefix via `npm config get prefix`
2. Go to that path
3. Copy executables you want under `bin/` i.e. `carto@`
4. Copy content you want from `lib/node_modules` i.e. `lib/node_modules/carto`
5. Apply to the machine you want using the same steps described here